# I upgraded Ubuntu on my laptop and I have to use the old GRUB entry for it to work

Tags: 10.10, boot, grub2

I upgraded Ubuntu on my laptop and I have to use the old boot link for it to work.  How can I make my laptop automatically use the working boot-up? When I use the new GRUB entry the screen goes blank and the computer seems to hang.

Answer (score 3):

you have to know the number of the working item

For example: The First line has number 0 , the second 1 etc.

Now

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And change the line    `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`
to

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=THEWORKINGNUMBER
```

now execute  `sudo update-grub`

Everything should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Install [startupmanager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/startupmanager) [image: Install startupmanager]

[image]

- In **Default operating sytem**,choose your old grub entry and click close.
- Reboot your system.